# Integrate recaptcha and wp_signon - what is needed?

Tags: login, errors, captcha

I've been using `wp_signon` for a long time in a project:

```
//Do the actual login for WP User
$creds = array();
$creds['user_login'] = $skuser_name;
$creds['user_password'] = $skuser_pass;
$creds['remember'] = true;
$user = wp_signon( $creds, false );
```

This have been working for a long time. I recently added plugin Wordfence which included recaptcha (invislbe) for login and registration forms and those obviously do work.

**After installation of that plugin** my custom loginforms with code above did **not** work.  After some research I figured out that it was the recaptcha in combination with my custom loginform that uses `wp_signon` that was the issue.

**I get the error** (when using correct username and password):

> //VERIFICATION REQUIRED: Additional verification is required for
>   login. Please check the email address associated with the account for
>   a verification link.

***When I deactive recaptcha which is included in WordFence - plugin*** -> **my custom loginform does work.**

I have keys that are needed for the actual recaptcha but I can't figure **what I have to do to** integrate this with `wp_signon`!? Is it possible to integrate recaptcha with `wp_signon` or do I have to create a custom wp_signon function?

Please point me in right direction! Thank you!

Comment: Wordfence has a filter named [`wordfence_ls_require_captcha`](https://www.wordfence.com/help/login-security/). Have you tried that?

Comment: I mean, you can use that filter *if* you just want to bypass the captcha while doing the `wp_signon()`. But if you actually want to add the captcha to your custom form, then you can ignore that filter.

Comment: @SallyCJ - thanks for telliing me about this. I did not know about this filter. This seems like a lazy mens way though. I really would want the recaptcha to work (integrated), not disabled - on my custom login forms.

Comment: Alright then. And I've posted an answer. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: @SallyCJ - wow thanks a LOT!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So [Wordfence](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordfence/) uses JavaScript to add the CAPTCHA fields to the login/registration form, but by default only on `https://example.com/wp-login.php`.

And if you want to add the fields to your form, or integrate the CAPTCHA security with your custom login form, the steps are:

1. Enqueue the (re)CAPTCHA scripts, preferably only on the page having the custom form:

   ```php
   add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', function () {
       if ( is_page( 'my-page' ) &&
           class_exists( '\WordfenceLS\Controller_WordfenceLS' )
       ) {
           \WordfenceLS\Controller_WordfenceLS::shared()->_login_enqueue_scripts();
       }
   } );
   ```

   The above would load the scripts only on the `my-page` Page, so you should change the slug or use another conditional tag like `is_single()`.
2. Your custom form *has to* meet these conditions:

   1. The username field must be named `log` (e.g. `<input name="log" />`).
   2. The password field must be named `pwd` (e.g. `<input name="pwd" />`).
   3. The submit button's `id` must be `wp-submit` (e.g. `<input id="wp-submit" type="submit" />`).
   4. There must be no other forms having those fields, i.e. there must be no other form fields having the **same `name` or `id`**.
   5. Wordfence will run an AJAX request to check the credentials and when there's an error like wrong password, Wordfence will add the error message after a `h1` (heading level 1) inside the element with the `id` of `login`.

      So you need to make sure those two elements (`#login` and `#login > h1`) both exist — see the sample form code below.

   And those are, unfortunately, limitations in the Wordfence's custom login script, which you can find it in `wp-content/plugins/wordfence/modules/login-security/js` and the file name looks like `login.1581523568.js` (i.e. `login.<numbers>.js`). You may copy and modify the script (i.e. remove those 5 limitations), then enqueue it *instead of* the default, but you'll need to try doing so on your own.

   Also, if you use [`wp_login_form()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_login_form/) (with a custom `action` value), you would only need to add the elements mentioned in #5 above.

**Code I used for testing:**

The form, shown on `https://example.com/my-page/`:

```html
<div id="login">
    <h1>Login</h1>

    <!-- Wordfence places AJAX error here -->

    <form method="post" action="">
        <input name="log" type="text" placeholder="Username" />
        <input name="pwd" type="password" placeholder="Password" />

        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="my_login" />
        <?php wp_nonce_field( 'my-login' ); ?>

        <input type="submit" id="wp-submit" />
    </form>
</div>
```

And the PHP, which calls `wp_signon()`:

```php
add_action( 'init', function () {
    if (
        wp_doing_ajax() || empty( $_POST['_wpnonce'] ) ||
        ( ! ( isset( $_POST['log'], $_POST['pwd'] ) ) ) ||
        ! wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['_wpnonce'], 'my-login' )
    ) {
        return;
    }

    $creds = array();

    $creds['user_login']    = $_POST['log'];
    $creds['user_password'] = $_POST['pwd'];
    $creds['remember']      = true;

    $user = wp_signon( $creds, false );
    if ( is_wp_error( $user ) ) {
        wp_die( $user );
    } else {
        wp_redirect( home_url( wp_get_referer() ) );
        exit;
    }
} );
```

### Additional Notes

As I mentioned in the comment, if you just want to bypass the CAPTCHA validation while doing `wp_signon()`, you can use the [`wordfence_ls_require_captcha` filter](https://www.wordfence.com/help/login-security/):

```php
add_filter( 'wordfence_ls_require_captcha', '__return_false' );
// call wp_signon() here
remove_filter( 'wordfence_ls_require_captcha', '__return_false' );
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It would be foolish NOT to accept this answer. I don't think it could be any clearer than this.

Comment: So would you mind marking the answer as correct, unless you intend to write your own answer? :)

Comment: ofc! I thought it was marked as accepted when I gave away my 200 points (Why else would I do that (asking SO here)). I apolgoize and thanks one again!

Comment: Nope, awarding a bounty does not automatically accept the answer (or mark it as correct), just as accepting an answer doesn't automatically upvote the answer.. eheh. :) Anyway, +1 for the question! ;)

Comment: Extremely helpful, @sally-cj Thank you!  I just wanted to add that after implementing this, I couldn't access the WP admin area, I'd get sent to the standard login page with `?reauth=1`. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9548457/how-to-log-the-user-in-the-correct-way-in-wordpress) gave me the solution, which was to call `wp_set_auth_cookie($user->ID);` after `wp_signon`. Doesn't seem like it should be necessary, but it solved my problem.